# Access ID does not work when testing a textfield with `isSecureTextEntry = true`

Tags: swift, xcode, io, xctest, xcuitest

So i am trying to access and confirm the presence of a password textfield in my uitests but as soon as assign their `isSecureTextEntry = true` the tests can no longer find them by the accessID. Does any one know why? and if there is a way around this so that i can find them and use them in the tests? Preferably so that i can still use the access ID to locate them in the tests.

My test is very simple:

```
func testHasPasswordTextField() {
    let passwordTextField = app.textFields[AccesID.passwordTextField]

    XCTAssertTrue(passwordTextField.isHittable)
}
```

I get the following error when running the test:

*"No matches found for Find: Elements matching predicate '"Password" IN identifiers' from input {(
    TextField, 0x600000193e80, traits: 146029150208, identifier: 'Email', placeholderValue: 'Email'
)}*".

the test passes happily if `isSecureTextEntry = false`(or just not set)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so  a colleague just found out for me that when testing and finding a textfield by its `accessabilityidentifier` and `isSecureTextEntry` is set to true the textfield is now found in tests as `secureTextFields` so my test passes as before but now looks like this:

```
func testHasPasswordTextField() {
    let passwordTextField = app.secureTextFields[AccesID.passwordTextField]

    XCTAssertTrue(passwordTextField.isHittable)
}
```